# Complexity OpenGL and Vulkan

Tags: opengl, directx, complexity-theory, vulkan

i was thinking about beginnig to learn OpenGL (of course the core profile) until i read a preview of a book where i found the attached graphic.

[image: effort and time consumption vs program complexity]

When i saw this first time, i was a little bit shocked. At the beginning my programs will not be huge and complex, but with time they will. Now i am thinking about learning Vulkan (i found a very comprehensible book) or switch to DirectX 11 oder 12(i am programming under windows).

**And here are some questions:**
*Has anyone here ever written programs with OpenGL that were so extensive and complex that at some point they were no longer feasible in terms of time and effort?*

*Is it the same with DirectX that with increasing program size the amount of time required increases and at some point is no longer feasible?*

*Regarding the attached graphics, is that the reason why games are written in DirectX instead of OpenGL?*

Answer (score -2, accepted):

As someone who made a game engine I can tell you that modern openGL is a powerful tool which can definitely run a game. Its not a toy and can drive you basically to triple A level. The reason why games for windows use DirectX is because DirectX is the graphics API for windows made by microsoft.

When you create a game engine the rendering API isn't something you're going to deal with all the time.

You are mostly going to wrap it up in your on stuff so making calls to OpenGL isn't something you're going to do that much anyway . In fact you'll probably want to implement both DirectX rendering and OpenGL rendering and Vulkan rendering to give the user a choice, you just implement it and forget it there somewhere in the core of the engine.

Which ever one you choose out of the three will do the work on whatever scale your project is. Some may be more optimized for your system and give you overall better performance. OpenGL won't limit you.
I suggest starting out with openGL and cpp. you can get real work done with it and be cross platform(forget the mac). If you only care about windows than you should use DirectX it's The API for windows and Xbox you'll have a great time with it.

Answer (score 2):

I do not have the book to which you are referring, but I would say that the graph is generally correct, so long as:

1. You replace "Previous graphics API" with "OpenGL and Direct3D pre-12".
2. You replace "Vulkan" with "Vulkan and Direct3D 12".
3. You replace "effort and time consumption" with "effort needed to optimize".
4. You replace "program complexity and size" with "rendered scene complexity and size"

The dichotomy is not Vulkan vs. everything else. It's immediate APIs (OpenGL/D3D11) vs. command-buffer APIs (Vulkan/D3D12). And the thing that makes immediate APIs difficult to work with is not what your program does; it's how your program has to interact with the GPU.

Immediate APIs hide many aspects of memory management behind abstractions. As such, if you need to do very specific things with memory (which you only need to do in high-performance scenarios involving large, complex scenes), then those APIs tend to get in your way.

Command buffer APIs tend to expose more of the low-level details of memory management. They directly present to you the dichotomy between raw blocks of memory and specific uses of that memory (buffers&textures). They expose the specific pools of memory and ways of allocating that memory that the implementation supports, and they force you to ask it which kinds of memory objects can go into which pools. And so forth.

But you get a lot more control over what's going on. That control only really matters if you're doing something that *needs* that control.

If you're making a highly complicated program like Civilization IV... you actually generally *don't care* about that control. Why? Because the complexity of CivIV is *not* about it's rendering system; its complexity is in the actual gameplay, AI, and so forth. Sure, command buffer APIs might still help performance-wise, but rendering performance is not likely to be the bottleneck.

> Has anyone here ever written programs with OpenGL that were so extensive and complex that at some point they were no longer feasible in terms of time and effort?

That's the wrong interpretation of the graph.

The domain of "impossible to do" means essentially that you could be getting better rendering performance, but OpenGL/D3D11 don't *let you access it*. That is, no matter how well you optimize your code, there is a hard limit on how fast you get.

That domain is primarily about the fact that immediate APIs don't have an effective way to thread rendering. All of their rendering stuff has to happen on the same thread. That means that your rendering performance will be limited by how fast the CPU's clock speed and instruction throughput (and cache architecture, and a bunch of other things).

So if your scene is sufficiently complex to fully saturate a single thread of the CPU, there's not much more that an immediate API can do to make your scene render faster. There are optimizations to improve throughput, but once you have employed all of those... you're out of tricks.

Command buffer APIs are *designed* for threaded rendering. A single thread submits the commands, but commands can be generated on any thread. This makes it theoretically possible to achieve a higher command throughput in command-buffer APIs that would be allowed by immediate APIs.